# What's the difference between math.stackexchange and mathematica.stackexchange?

Tags: discussion, se-sites

I've noticed that very recently there has been a new site, [mathematica.stackexchange.com](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/).

It appears to be fairly new and very similar to [this site](http://math.stackexchange.com).

What's the difference?  It doesn't appear too obvious to me.

Comment: I'm afraid that I must wonder what research you've done before asking the question. Especially considering that there's a giant information box that pops up for me in the link the question that starts with the sentence "Mathematica Stack Exchange is a question and answer site **for users of Mathematica**" (emphasis mine), combined with the fact that as soon as I go to the [site tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour), the very first thing I see is "Mathematica® Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for users of Wolfram Mathematica and the Wolfram Language."

Comment: I think the number of downvotes exemplifies the fact that sometimes we don't tolerate "silly" questions and this happens a lot in M.SE, sadly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Mathematica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematica) is a software used for symbolic computation and other computational mathematics. It is akin to [Wolfram|Alpha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfram_Alpha) (both come from the same company).

The Mathematica.SE website is dedicated for that *software* and its uses. This website is not for questions about mathematical software, as much as it is about mathematics.

(It's also not very new, with [the first question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1/usage-of-invisibleapplication-and-other-related-invisible-characters) from 4 years ago.)

Comment: Oh, that makes sense.  :D  Thank you.  If it isn't new, I must've never seen it.  Thanks!

Comment: @Martin: Thanks!